# Node.js require doesn’t get a module

Tags: node.js

I’m putting logs in my Node.js app. I’ve created logger module in applog.js using winston library, and imported it to all other modules. It’s working fine in most module, but it doesn’t work in one module. 
Code for importing is

```
const applog = require(‘../app/logging/applog’)
```

The path is correct. It doesn’t throw a error while importing it. However, it returns and empty object `{}`
When I tried to use it like

```
applog.info(‘logging message’)
```

It threw an exception, and the error message is `applog.info is not a function`

====> Solved it. Thank you for the comments. Explanations are below.

applog file has logging configuration, and the logs are pushed to console and Elasticsearch. Recently I’ve created Vault module(file) to get id and password for ES, and ES config file is calling it. So When I put 
const applog = require(‘../app/logging/applog’) 
to Vault, it got an empty applog. Because applog needed ES, ES needed Vault and Vault needed applog. My stupid mistakes. I’ve removed applog from Vault and everything is working fine.

Comment: what is your folder structure?

Comment: Lucy if you add more about your folder structure and build environment you'll get a better answer here. Also wouldn't hurt to put together a basic stackblitz that show's your problem to help us properly diagnose your issue.

Comment: Are the quotes like that actually in your code?

Comment: What is your folder structure? Also show us the other module code where you have imported this logger module.